# Edit the catalog page for specific category

Tags: magento, seo, magento-1.8

I am using Magento 1.8.1 and I am working on SEO. I need to put micro-data (schema code) for some category on that page only. I don't understand how to put the data for specific page because if I put any data in template page, it will update on all categories.

For example: I need to put data only for [this page](http://littlebees.com/index.php/toys-game/baby-toys-0-2-yrs/block-and-stacking-games.html).

Comment: You could create a new category attribute "display_micro_data" for example, and display the data according to this boolean

Comment: you only need to set that data once on only one page?

Comment: @adrien54: how i add attribute for catagory ?

Comment: Programmatically. But look at David Tay's answer, the additional layout directives seem to be a better solution for you if it's just for one category.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to add some code to only appear on a specific category view. You can add Javascript to the description field in the General Information tab of the category:

[image: Category General Information tab]

You can also add a template to before_body_end block of the page:

[image: Category Custom Design tab]

You can add additional layout directives here. This layout update:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" name="seocode" template="seocode/seocode.phtml" />
</reference>
```

means render out your custom block (seocode) and template file (seocode.phtml) in the before_body_end block. The before_body_end block can be found in the page templates; i.e. page/1column.phtml or page/2columns-left.phtml.

Comment: thanks for  reply, i don't want to show data on front end, i want to kept it in backend only. if i create a layout , then where i put that data? where  that layout  found?

Comment: Create a folder and template file (seocode/seocode.phtml used above as an example) and put it in your theme. In the template, you can put in any Javascript.